# different package name because "com.example" is restricted

Tags: android

Sorry for changing this question, it was mymistake, i wrongly uploaded the old apk file..thanks

New problem..I am facing this error while uploading signed apk file..

```
You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.
```

I just able to generate the signed apk file and went to 'show in explorer' and name of the file is `app-release.apk` and i went to developer console to upload the same file, after uploading, i got the above error.

I have removed the debuggable true from build.gradle and no android:debuggable="true" to the  element in androidmanifest.xml

i changed the settings from file-> project structure -> signing (entered keystroke values) then build types selected 'realease'.  and then 'ok' then i went to Build -> build signed apk -> existing values & password -> next -> release -> ok, and then uploaded the same apk to developer console. same error

Any idea to resolve it .. Thanks

Comment: Dud you tried removing the debug attribute from your AndroidManifest file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> Make sure you deactivate logging and disable the debugging option
>   before you build your application for release. You can deactivate
>   logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files. You can
>   disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute from
>   the tag in your manifest file, or by setting the android:debuggable
>   attribute to false in your manifest file. Also, remove any log files
>   or static test files that were created in your project.

Also, you should remove all `Debug` tracing calls that you added to your code, such as `startMethodTracing()` and `stopMethodTracing()` method calls.
[Link:](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-configure)

So in your project manifest xml file, change the debuggable attribute to false.

Comment: i changed the settings from file-> project structure -> signing (entered keystroke values) then build types selected 'realease'.  and then 'ok' then i went to Build -> build signed apk -> existing values & password -> next -> release -> ok, and then uploaded the same apk to developer console. same error

Answer (score 0):

The package name is specified in the AndroidManifest.xml. Check the value there.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, can you help me with this problem "You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs"